# Can't Download File in Selenium Docker Using Python

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I pulled image from docker python:3.10 and installed chrome&selenium.
but when tried trigger a download action by button-click.can't find any file in the directory or filename like *.crdownload.
the python script has no problem when ran in local or google colab.in docker the chrome version is 114.*
Any advice is appreciated.

Want to find the downloading file named *.crdownload in directory
My chrome setting :

```
prefs = {"download.default_directory": download_path}
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Dockerfile:

```
ENV HOME=/home/user \
    PATH=/home/user/.local/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR $HOME/app
RUN python3 --version
RUN apt-cache show chromium
COPY --chown=user . $HOME/app
CMD ["python3","app.py"]
```

Comment: Docker does not have persistent storage. Did you mount a persistent drive? You should include all information how you set up your Docker image and where you are trying to download the file to.

Comment: Actually , I have built a image based on ubuntu:18 and the *.crdownload file can be found in HOME path when the file is downloading.
But have no idea to update the python version to 3.8+ so I switched to current image.@SiKing
And for some reason, I can't mount a volume.